# Limit a view to only invited users Laravel Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am looking for a way to show a specific view only to specific visitors who get a link to that view. How can I make a middleware so that shows the view only if it comes from a specific source (like if it comes from source.blade.php)

I cannot use the middleware for guest or auth, because then it would give that view to all the auth, but I only want give that view to an auth who has made a payment at beginning and have been redirected from a specific URL.

How can I setup a middleware in such a way that it only shows the view if the auth is being redirected from another view like - `source.blade.php`

Currently, I have this page setted up like this

```
public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('auth:client');
    }
```

This works well, it only shows this page to someone who has logged in from the client authentication guard, but the problem is, any client can visit this page.

I am looking for a way to make it so that it can viewed only by the client who paid at the beginning, and were re-directed by my website. Maybe something like

```
public function __construct()
    {
        if(redirect_source="source.blade.php") {$this->middleware('auth:client'); }
    }
```

Comment: You could include an authentication token in the link that expires after a certain period. JWT is ideal for this.

Comment: Your question is way too broad and lacks any useful context. Can you try and add more detail please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the question and added some codes to make it specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a solution that will limit the permission based on your user type.

Middlewares are used to condition certain parameters if you want to let the requester to go into the specific url/route and not to control inside your views.

So if you want to control it, you can use this solution .

```
    namespace App\Laravel\Middleware\Backoffice;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Auth, Session;

class ValidSuperUser {

/**
 * The Guard implementation.
 *
 * @var Guard
 */
protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new filter instance.
 *
 * @param  Guard  $auth
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($this->auth->user()->type != "super_user") {
        Session::flash('notification-status','failed');
        Session::flash('notification-title',"Access Denied");
        Session::flash('notification-msg','You are not allowed to view the page you are tring to access.');
        return redirect()->route('backoffice.dashboard');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

in your Kernel.php under Http folder declare the new Middleware in order to use.

**put it under protected $routeMiddleware = []

and then use it to your routes that need to help that kind of user type.

```
$route->group(['middleware' => "aliasofyournewmiddle"],function(){
   //some routes here
});
```

your new middleware can be any condition upon the request, so any inputs and available session that has been passed to that url are usable on that middleware, adjust it on how you want to handle the situation.

Comment: How does this work? How can I use this to limit users to let's say `premium.blade.php` ?

Comment: you can create additional middleware on your app and declaring in to your Kernel.  then you can use that to your route 

example to my additional middleware 

'aliasofmiddleware' => App\Laravel\Middleware\Backoffice\ ValidSuperUser;

and then when i use this in my route

$route->group(['middleware' => "aliasofmiddleware"],function(){
      //your route for superuser only.
});

Comment: Thanks, it works great. My only problem remains is that, when you click back button after logged out, it still shows the view, will registering on that view work? Will middleware remove any functionality from that view if pressed back button?

Comment: You will need to have a cookie or session checker on your js script. Cause any action on your browser actionbar can only be controlled on js script :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a token when redirecting your users to your specific page. Then use your middleware to check whether that token is valid or not.

Say for example, someone *made a payment at beginning*, you store a hash value of that person's user id or any unique identifier in a session, then redirect the user with the same hash value included in your url. Your middleware can then handle the validation, if the value stored in the session is the same with the value provided in the url.